# Akka for Java, how to use an an Actor with generics

Tags: java, generics, akka

[Akka](http://akka.io) seems like a nice framework/concept for working with asynchronous flows in your application. I am currently learning Akka for one of my projects and I was wondering about how to properly design Actors.

Imagine the following actor:

```
public class SampleActor extends UntypedActor {
    private final LoggingAdapter log = 
            Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof SomeType) {
            SomeType someType = ((SomeType) message);
            // Handle SomeType
        } else if (message instance SomeOtherType) {
            SomeOtherType someOtherType = ((SomeOtherType) message);
            // Handle SomeOtherType
        } else {
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is a common pattern that is e.g. described in the [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/java/untyped-actors.html).

The pattern above seems kind of *old school* to me with a bunch of `instanceof` checks and that the actor handles `Object`. Is there another preferred approach for this (like some base class where you specify the types you are interested in) or similar.

One alternative that I can see is that you e.g inherit a generic actor such as:

```
public class SampleActor extends GenericActor<SomeType> {
    public void onReceive(final SomeType someType) throws Exception {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

So, what is the best practice for working with actors. Is it extending `UntypedActor` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

First of all look on the `UntypedActor` and `onReceive` method contract which was designed for Scala pattern-matching and **there is some beauty in ths simplified design.**

Using Java, you need some sort of trade off. You can use your custom implementation of `Visitor` pattern for each actor but it adds unnecessary effort.

The best is to use `AbstractActor` with its `PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receive()` method, supported by your own abstraction.

```
public abstract class AbstractAggregateRegistryActor extends AbstractActor {

    @Override
    public PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receive() {
        return ReceiveBuilder.
                match(Protocol.AbstractComponentRegister.class, 
                                      this::handleRegistration).
                match(Protocol.AbstractComponentDeregister.class,
                                      this::handleDeregistration).
                match(Protocol.AbstractComponentRegistryRequest.class,
                                      this::handleRegistryRequest).
                matchAny(this::unhandled).build();
    }


    private void handleRegistration(Protocol.AbstractComponentRegister
                                    componentRegister) {
        .....
    }

    private void handleDeregistration(Protocol.AbstractComponentDeregister
                                      componentDeregister) {
        ...
    }

    protected abstract <T extends Protocol.AbstractComponentRegistryRequest> 
                         void handleRegistryRequest(T registryRequest);


    @Override
    public void unhandled(Object message) {
        log.warning("Unhandled message {} in registry.", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Frankly I found it ugly in Scala as well. I mean yeah cool you can use pattern-matching, but it seems to me the API are designed for using a language functionality at all costs in this way.

It would be nicer if you can actually put a generic on that actor and consequently the receive method can be more specific and if you need to receive different kind of messages put a trait on it and then use pattern-matching.

Just my 2-cents.